# why arrays as key in json format not valid?

Tags: arrays, json

This probably has no direct use case. But I am wondering why the following is considered as invalid json

```
{"hello": 
   {[1,2,3,4] : "foobar" }
}
```

Comment: Side note: Would be interesting to know what you expect this to do. Or what language allows such indexing of properties by array...

Comment: as I mentioned in the post, there is no use case I can think of.

Answer (score 5):

This is invalid because JSON objects are based on name/value pairs. Simply put, an array is not a name. The name is an identifier, it doesn't (and shouldn't) contain any information or functionality. There's more details about the JSON specification at [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/).

From the page above:

> JSON is built on two structures:
>
> - A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is
>     realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed
>     list, or associative array.
> - An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.

Answer (score 3):

*Why* is just because this is what was decided upon by whoever created JSON.  As for why they did that, it is probably to match JavaScript for which this would also be invalid.

An array is an object, so `[1,2,3,4] != [1,2,3,4]`.  This would make it impossible to dereference the object property if it were declared like this inline since there would be no reference to the array in the object declaration.

If you were to do something like

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
```

The there would be no way to distinguish between a property named `arr` (valid in Javascript, `{arr: "value"}`) and the interpolated array value.

Semantically, there is no benefit to having arrays as keys.  Keys are not typically properties to be operated on -- they are merely identifiers.

Answer (score 2):

> why the following is considered as invalid json

Because it does not obey the JSON spec.

JSON defines an interchange format for JavaScript objects. JavaScript objects are and always have been and always will be a collection of pairs of **string-valued keys** and values.

Arrays are not valid string-valued keys for JavaScript object properties. There are JavaScript "maps" which allow objects as keys, but they are distinct from JavaScript objects.

Comment: `string-valued keys`  is the key take here!